# Error when opening app on different computer

Tags: sql-server, database, localdb, mdf

I have just finished an app that is using a `database.mdf`.  Everything is working well, but when I open the app on a different computer, I'm getting the following error:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified) "

Here is the database connection string:

> Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=Z:\Items\ItemDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=60

All computers have this network storage drive already mapped to the computer, but it only seems to work on my computer.

I have tried the double `\\` but nothing worked. The names all match. What could it be?

Thanks

Comment: Should have to mapped drive Z: on every computer that you opening your application

Comment: Could also be permissions. IIRC the user needs full read + write permissions and this error will be thrown if they don't.

Comment: are there other things that have it open at the same time?

Comment: on other computers, is `Z:` drive mapped to the exact same share?  If `Z:` is mapped in a logon screen, and program is running as different user, could it be that `Z:` exists, but is pointing to a different folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect to Server :A network-related or instance-specific error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error) and about 50 others located searching here for the first sentence in the quoted error message (and not to mention the 200K+ results that turned up with a Google search on the same sentence, many of which were here).

Comment: Look that he is using SQL Express LocalDB 2012 and the error message says "Error Locating Server/Instance Specified". It is not a problem with the file or the drive `Z:`

Comment: Some things to check: http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331

Comment: The article miss the SQL LocalDB, is a completely new way of access SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer which you are trying to run the application must have the LocalDB installed.

You can download it from this link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Comment: i tried your suggestion but i'm having permission issue with installing the sql server localdb.msi due to the computers are on a domain. you wouldn't happen to know of a different method or maybe a different type of database to use that wont request any kind on software install before use?

Comment: To install SQL Server Local DB you must be an administrator. It is one of main disadvantages when compared to SQL Compact DB.